# Auto spacing between inline divs

Tags: html, spacing

How can I set spacing between divs to "auto" inside fluid width parent div? Is it even possible with CSS only? 
More specific:
I have some parent div width `width: 90%`. I have 3 inline elements inside it. I want first element to touch left side of my parent div, second element to be in middle, and last element to touch right side of the parent div.

@edit:
I'm adding some code:

```
#news-pane {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 90%;
}

#news {
    color: #333;
    width: 300px;;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}

#news img {
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="news-pane">
    <li id="news">
        <div id="news-header">
           <h1>Title</h1><span>Date</span>
        </div>
        <p><News content</p>
    </li>
    <li id="news">
        <div id="news-header">
           <h1>Title</h1><span>Date</span>
        </div>
        <p><News content</p>
    </li>
    <li id="news">
        <div id="news-header">
           <h1>Title</h1><span>Date</span>
        </div>
        <p><News content</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the first element `float:left`, the second element with auto margins and the third element `float:right`. AFAIK the elements have to be block for this to work.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2CmSK/

---

EDIT after seeing the code: The main problem is that you're using the same id for multiple elements. You have to use unique ids or use classes instead. The HTML is invalid right now and might behave unpredictably in different browsers.

The second problem is that the outer div's width is given in percentages and the news items' width is given in pixels. If the user's browser window is less than 1000px wide the outer div will be less than 900px wide and the news items won't fit inside.

And between the lines I'm reading that you're using some kind of closed/standard tool to generate the news items so you can't modify the code and they all have to have the same structure. If this is the case then no, you can't have them behave differently if they are structurally identical without using JavaScript.

Comment: More specific they are set to inline-block. Those are news with image, title, date and some text. If I set `inline` then strange things happen - my div (which width is set to 300px) tries to fill whole parent div and takes parent width...

Comment: Yeah, I've added code already to my question. Thanks for your answer. Is there a away to achieve what I want without possibility to aim specific news div? So is there some rule I can set for every div and it will works?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can use classes to target multiple divs. You need to show the HTML you have.

Comment: Html added to main question. Adding class like "first", "second" and "last" is not the solution

Comment: Yeah, this code is printed by WordPress. I have ofcourse some ability to change the output but I think JavaScript will be easier to do and I will stay with it. Thank you for your help.